# Counter siege tank mass with certain build?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm using this build from [filtersc](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3BEC8845BD92A381&feature=plcp).  It's basically a MMM build (Marine, Marauder, Medivac) with +1 attack, stim, and combat shield.  I feel like I win every single game using it except those against opponents who mass tanks.  How do I counter this with the build that I have?

Comment: scout see factories then pop out more marauders than marines.

Comment: But what if they also have air attacks? I've faced enemies with battlecruisers and tanks.

Comment: you MUST scout, the BC and tank need a lot gas, at less 2 bases, and the BC will pop out at min seven with maybe 2 or 3 tank, easily raped by a drop of marauders and marines, everything it is about economy and scout

Comment: i am pretty sure the oponets who mass tanks vs you they scout you 4  barracks, I play zerg if i scout 4 barrack or more then pop out zerling ,banelings and roaches

Comment: I always scout.

Comment: then if you see the factories why you don't change a little your army?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two answers, assuming you can't simply outplay your opponent.

- Drops
- Sky Terran

Drops means you utilize your Medivacs to attack areas where he has few tanks. Tanks gain their power because they are able to eliminate large groups of units before those units have a chance to fire. When there are only two or three tanks, they can't really do this and so you're capable of taking fights that are very cost-effective for you. As soon as the game swings beyond 3-base vs. 3-base, you have a huge mobility advantage and with 2 or 3 full Medivacs you can easily deny your opponent expansions or take out under-fortified troops. At this point, the only thing you really have to fear is a single massive attack. Beating this attack can be difficult but the main reason you'll beat it is again, with drops. As you see him start to move out, drop a few full Medivacs into his production line and that way you'll force him to pull his attack back or win the game outright with no reinforcements. Then you'll just have to trade effectively and

With Sky Terran, or air play, you gain a higher Viking count and use it in conjunction with Banshees and later possibly Battlecruisers or Ravens to force unsieges and win engagements. You can do this because you should have significantly more gas than your opponent, as he's invested into Tanks and you haven't. This also gives you free reign to drop as you please. The main issue here is that transitioning to Sky Terran leaves you very open to an attack as you do so, because he'll be hitting the critical mass of tanks that he needs to devastate you with an attack just as you start to gain air control.

The only other answer is to outmicro him by picking off out of position tanks, splitting units effectively, flanking, dropping lines of units into his tank line to negate their splash power, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  I have in fact used these tactics, but usually the opponent has anticipated and surrounded his base with turrets.

Answer (score 2):

Countering Siege Tanks with MMM is not that easy and there is no cute timing that will help you win. You have to rely on multiple factors to secure your win.

You cannot lay back, expand get your tech and your MMM ball and a move to the win.

Rules:

- The bigger the armies get the harder it is for you to win. Keep the armies small by attacking and harassing constantly if possible.
- With Siege Tanks position is everything. Do not let him move his tanks freely, make him leap forward every single inch. This will demolish low APM players as they will slip in Macro.

Here are some tactics that you can incorporate into your game:

- Take far away expansions, as you are mobile and he is not. Especially in a base race you will win if you have a base in every corner of the map.
- Once you get a huge amount of Medivacs try to doom drop into his base while he is sieged up in the middle of the map. This means load all Marines and Marauders into the Medivacs and drop wherever he is vulnerable (e.g. main base).
- Always scout where his main force is and when it unsieges. This is the only time you can safely attack.
- Attack at multiple locations at once to force him to split his army (see first rule)
- Try to split your army before you attack into the siege tanks.
- Try to attack from multiple directions, as this way your units are more spread out.
- At later stages of the game build siege tanks yourself to prevent him from leaping forward into your base.

If you drag the game into the very late game try to go air. A Battlecruiser, Banshee, Viking mix with some Marines in the back will crush Siege Tanks. He has to rely on Marines to counter this because of his huge gas investments.

Comment: I forgot to mention Ghosts. You can use Nukes to force unsieges. Cancel the nuke with ESC when he starts to unsiege and stim right into his tanks. It is even better if he stays. Use cloak and try to stay out of range of his tanks (use the huge area of effect of nukes).

Comment: Can you give an example (preferably a VOD) of how to delay and delay and delay the tank push across the map? I imagine you'd also have to use tanks or banshees, but I'm curious about the MMM tactics.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using banshees.

If you go MMM, then you'll have some tech labs with your Barracks. Swap them with your Starport and make some Banshees. If you want you can research stealth too. Anyway they are pretty good against tanks ;)

If you have stealth you can hide the banshees. The best way is to attack with just one stealthed banshee so your enemy will waste his radar for just one banshee. You can then attack with all your stealthed banshees. Otherwise you can focus tanks and try to attack Marines with your Marauders.

Comment: How do you use banshees effectively when the tanks are protected by marines or turrets?

Comment: If you have stealth you can hide the banshees. The best way is to attack with just one stealthed banshee so your enemy will waste his radar for just one banshee. You can then attack with all your stealthed banshees. Otherwise you can focus tanks and try to attack Marines with your Marauders.

Comment: That's a great addition to your answer. You can click 'edit' and add that in. Or if you'd like, I can help you edit the question too.

Comment: Also, do you have an example vods of this tactic?

Comment: I couldn't find a video on this tactic and unfortunately I don't have one by myself,but I found this video http://youtu.be/6l487jq9ki8 about Banshees vs Marines!Hope you like it:) P.s.:I'm not saying you're a noob,it's just the only video I could find that looks helpful:) @BBz

Comment: Ah it's ok, I'm just helping to improve this answer. To me (I'm a BW player) banshees would make a lot of sense, since wraiths were effective at harassing tank lines if you had good control and multitasking. But I haven't seen banshees used against tank lines (or many tank lines at all in TvT for that matter) in tournament play, so I was wondering what causes this difference.